# How do tags inherit from each other?

Tags: css

I have the following definition for p:

```
.contact p {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
    font-size:0.875em;
    color: gray;  
}
```

I would like the email link below to inherit everything from p as well:

```
.contact a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `.contact a` to have the same style as your `p`, just list your selectors, separated by a comma, like this:

```
.contact p, .contact a {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
    font-size:0.875em;
    color: gray;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.contact p, .contact a {
    /* your styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no inheritance available in CSS in that manner. You will have to modify the `.contact p` selector so that it selects the `a` as well. Something like:

```
.contact p, .contact a { /* Your styling */ }
```

Another option is to use a CSS pre-processor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which extends CSS with some handy features like variables, mixins, nested rules etc. Using mixins and variables in LESS, you could accomplish inheritance something like this:

```
.rounded-corners (@radius: 5px) {
  border-radius: @radius;
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
  -moz-border-radius: @radius;
}

#header {
  .rounded-corners;
}
#footer {
  .rounded-corners(10px);
}
```

Comment: You must not have heard of the `inherit` keyword.

Comment: @BoltClock Well I have indeed, but the question do not state that the a element is a child of p.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that... I guess I misread the question in a way.